# I encountered these problems when I went into the manually built kernel in grub for Ubuntu 23.04 Server

Tags: kernel, g++

1. List item

BUG: KCSAN: data-race in __hrtimer_run_queues / hrtimer_active

1. List item

BUG: KCSAN: data-race in tick_sched_do_timer / tick_sched_do_timer

1. List item

BUG: KCSAN: data-race in do_nanosleep / hrtimer_wakeup

[image]]

Comment: I guess you built a kernel which has a bug. That's all I can **guess** from your question.